# Using python multiprocessing to execute more than 100 db2 queries

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, db2

I am quite new to multiprocessing and threading. I am trying to come up with a solution where I have to execute multiple db2 queries in parallel, so that I can get the results fast.

I have come up with the following code:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing
import os
import sys
import ibm_db

executed_queries = []


class QueryRunner:
    def __init__(self, files):
        self.files = files

    def execute_query(self, filename):
        with ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=sample;HOSTNAME=localhost;PORT=50000;USERNAME=db2admin;PASSWORD=db2admin") as conn:
            with open(filename) as f:
                query = f.read()
            print(f"Executing query: {query}")

            for i in range(3):
                try:
                    ibm_db.exec_query(conn, query)
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Query failed with error: {e}")
            else:
                # Query failed after 3 retries
                print(f"Query failed after 3 retries")
                # Check if the for loop executed any iterations
                if not i:
                    # The for loop did not execute any iterations, so replace the query with a different query
                    filename = next((f for f in self.files if f not in executed_queries and f.startswith('MYqueries'))]
                    self.execute_query(filename)

    def run(self):
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=15) as pool:
            results = pool.starmap(self.execute_query, [(filename,) for filename in filenames])

            for result in results:
                print(f"Query complete: {result}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = os.listdir('.')
    filenames = [f for f in files if f not in executed_queries and f.startswith('MYqueries')]
    query_runner = QueryRunner(filenames)
    query_runner.run()
```

I am getting TypeError continuously in pool.starmap()

I have all the queries stored as separate txt files in the folder MYqueries. I am reading from the folder and try to execute multiple queries parallelly for faster operations. Any help would be great in this regard.

Thanks
Also, if I have made a lot of fundamental mistakes, do point out. I would try to amend all those.

after using `sys.exc_info()` in my run() method, I am getting following results:
`(<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError('QueryRunner.execute_query takes 2 positional arguments but 20 were given'), <traceback object at 0x0000025F1454D680>)`

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: Thanks, Can you suggest how I can get that? In my console, I am just getting a single line of error, which I have typed above

Comment: @learner_account if you are using windows, i think you can just copy paste. I use wsl and that works here too.

Comment: I have added the traceback for the same

Comment: Using a class here offers no benefits over simple functions and appears to be causing confusion. Do you know if the IBM connection "handle" is thread-safe? If it is then you can improve performance significantly with multithreading. Unless you queries are complex it's quite possible that the time to connect is going to be longer than the query execution

Comment: Thanks for the response @DarkKnight 
the queries are quite complex and takes longer to execute. I made the code modular just for maintainability purpose a in future it is going to grow much bigger. Regarding whether IBM connection is thread-safe, I don't have much idea

Comment: "queries in parallel, so that I can get the results fast" might not work out if it causes conflicts in the database system (different areas of data, fight for buffer pool resources)

Comment: Instead of `starmap` you should try `results = pool.map(self.execute_query, filenames)`. If this doesn't work, follow the advise of @DarkKnight to not use a class and use a simple function instead of a method.

Comment: thanks for helping out. I will follow the advice and update what I got from following the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably have more questions than answers for you:

In your `for/else` statement you check:

```py
                # Check if the for loop executed any iterations
                if not i:
```

But you only reach this code if the `for` loop ran to completion leaving `i` with a value of 2. So I don't see how `not i` will ever evaluate to `True`. But if it does somehow evaluate to `True` you have the statement:

```py
                    filename = next((f for f in self.files if f not in executed_queries and f.startswith('MYqueries'))]
```

This does not compile. Perhaps you meant:

```py
                    filename = next(f for f in self.files if f not in executed_queries and f.startswith('MYqueries'))
```

If your intention is to get the next `filename` value from `self.files` that hasn't yet been executed, then this will not work. First and foremost, global `executed_queries` is not sharable among the pool's processes and you have no code to update this list even if it were sharable. Besides, the `run` method is already trying each element of `filenames`.

You have in method `QueryRunner.run`:

```py
            results = pool.starmap(self.execute_query, [(filename,) for filename in filenames])
```

Is `filenames` defined? Did you mean `self.filenames`?

Why not just:

```py
            results = pool.map(self.execute_query, self.filenames)
```

You then print out each element in the `results` list, but `execute_query` implicitly returns `None`. Until `execute_query` returns something meaningful, there is not much point in storing and printing the results.

Then you have:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = os.listdir('.')
    filenames = [f for f in files if f not in executed_queries and f.startswith('MYqueries')]
    ...
```

At this point in time `executed_queries` is empty so why are you even testing this?

**What I Would Do**

Since there is a cost to creating a connection, I would create one dedicated connection for each thread in a multithreading pool (since you `execute_query` is mostly waiting, multithreading is a viable, more efficient option that multiprocessing). You need to figure out what the optimal number of threads are.

```py
import ibm_db
import threading

def execute_query(self, filename):
    # Create a connection for this thread if it does not already exist:
    local_storage = threading.local()
    conn = getattr(local_storage, 'conn', None)
    if conn is None:
        conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=sample;HOSTNAME=localhost;PORT=50000;USERNAME=db2admin;PASSWORD=db2admin")
        localstorage.conn = conn # remember for next time

    with conn:
        with open(filename) as f:
            query = f.read()
        print(f"Executing query: {query}")

        for i in range(3):
            try:
                ibm_db.exec_query(conn, query)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Query failed with error: {e}")
            else:
                return # Success

        # Query failed after 3 retries
        print(f"Query failed after 3 retries")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from mutiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    import os

    files = os.listdir('.')
    filenames = [f for f in files if f.startswith('MYqueries')]
    # 15 threads (is there a better pool size?)
    with ThreadPool(15, initializer=init_pool) as pool:
        pool.map(execute_query, filenames)
```

Note that the way I coded `execute_query`, it can be invoked without it being a pool worker function.